# I want to visit Canada but I was deported from the US

Tags: usa, canada, legal, deportation

Last year I was deported from the US because I was "working" at some public events. I never got money from that because I was helping friends to run said events. Anyway, I am planning to go to a convention in Canada and wanted to know if me being deported from the US would be an issue here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: As you have discovered, just because you don't receive cash does not make it not work according to immigration law. I hope you're only planning to go to the convention in Canada and not double-down on this mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't state your citizenship(s), and that could play a factor here.

All you can do is try.  However, Canada and the US share a lot of immigration information, so Canada will be well aware of the problem you had in the US, and may need to be convinced that you won't repeat the behaviour.  If the border officer is unconvinced, you will not be permitted admission.  If you are asked about the incident and lie about it, you will not be permitted admission and may be banned for an extended period.

Comment: Indeed, it might be better to apply for a visa to avoid things depending quite so much on the individual immigration officer you meet.

Comment: It's probably also a Good Idea for OP to characterize the incident as a mistake or error of judgment, and *not* as "those meanies in the US threw me out on a technicality!"  The latter will not be taken well.